# How to globally monitor systemd unit states?

Tags: systemd, d-bus

I've been trying to come up with a script to monitor unit failures and be alerted by email globally (i.e. not using `OnFailure=` in each unit I want to monitor).

In the documentation, I found the `JobRemoved` D-Bus signal, which sounds exactly like what I'm looking for, only for jobs. In particular, this means that `Type=simple` units will trigger `JobRemoved` as soon as the child process is created and will not wait for it to end.

Is there a similar signal to globally monitor unit state changes?

*(This is my current attempt: [Link](https://gist.github.com/fxthomas/abeaf26aeefe2f2eb960f767470fd9d8))*

Answer (score 2):

You can connect to the [PropertiesChanged](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#standard-interfaces-properties) signal on each unit which is emitted whenever a property of a unit changes. The property *ActiveState*

> contains a state value that reflects whether the unit is currently active or not. The following states are currently defined: active, reloading, inactive, failed, activating, deactivating. active indicates that unit is active (obviously...). reloading indicates that the unit is active and currently reloading its configuration. inactive indicates that it is inactive and the previous run was successful or no previous run has taken place yet. failed indicates that it is inactive and the previous run was not successful (more information about the reason for this is available on the unit type specific interfaces, for example for services in the Result property, see below). activating indicates that the unit has previously been inactive but is currently in the process of entering an active state. Conversely deactivating indicates that the unit is currently in the process of deactivation.

(from the [systemd dbus docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/dbus/)).

To get an initial list of units, you can use the `ListUnits` method and subscribe to the `UnitNew` and `UnitRemoved` signals to get notified when units are added/removed.

There are multiple existing projects that already use this, including [systemd_mon](https://github.com/joonty/systemd_mon) and [sagbescheid](http://sagbescheid.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into these! I should have made my question clearer though : as far as I can tell these two projects require a list of units you want to monitor, right? I'd like to do the opposite : passively watch all unit state changes and react on a specific state, whatever the unit is. I edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: I've added some more information to my answer. AFAICT ListUnits and the signals are the only way to do what you want because there's no global signal for unit state changes. I'd love to be proven wrong though, sagbescheid is my project and it would be great to simplify it.

Comment: I didn't find anything either... During my tests `ListUnits` had issues (which I also found in `sagbescheid`) : it doesn't seem to return disabled service units that are only triggered by timers/other units. You can subscribe to `UnitNew` and `UnitRemoved` to get notified when they are loaded, but then you get thrice as many race conditions :)

Comment: Hm, after looking at it more carefully, it seems that my test case was flawed : my test unit had no `Install` section, which is why it was only loaded on unit startup (seen by `UnitNew`) and discarded afterwards (also seen in `UnitRemoved`). In any case, I'm leaving the question open until systemd gets a proper solution. I'll probably be using sagbescheid however.